# Package Python3.7 is not available

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, apt

So I have python 3.8 and pip for it, but I want to install stable python 3.7 and pip for it also. But when I try
`sudo apt-get install python3.7`
It says package is not available but is referred to another package.
Help please
Error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package python3.7 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3.7' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: as a workaround, try this https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Comment: btw which os are you using?

Comment: Nah, IDK doesn't work for me

Comment: Try `apt-cache search python3.7`. If it is listed, only then it is available for you.

Comment: @Paolo I use Kali Linux arm64

Comment: @Jhon  Strood ```python3-crypto - cryptographic algorithms and protocols for Python 3
python3-crypto-dbg - cryptographic algorithms and protocols for Python 3 (debug extension)
libpython3.7-minimal - Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.7)
libpython3.7-stdlib - Interactive high-level object-oriented language (standard library, version 3.7)
python3.7-minimal - Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.7)```

Comment: Looks like you only have a minimal version of python3.7. `sudo apt-get install python3.7-minimal`

Comment: @John Strood Yeap, if I execute ```python3.7``` it works nice, but ```pip``` says no module named ```distutil.utils```

Comment: Yes, that is the difference between `python` and `python-minimal`. You'll have to install every package.

Comment: @VasilySobolev - you can try re-installing pip: `curl -fsSL https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.7 -`

Comment: @VasilySobolev Install distutils using `sudo apt-get install python3-distutils`

Comment: @jakub File "<stdin>", line 23682, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 198, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 82, in bootstrap
  File "/tmp/tmphhbqk1xr/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmphhbqk1xr/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmphhbqk1xr/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmphhbqk1xr/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 18, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'

Comment: @Jhon Strood Already installed

Comment: @VasilySobolev Try `python3.7 -m pip install python3-setuptools`

Comment: @VasilySobolev Your best way to do this on any linux distro is using PPA. Try these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62508398/5337834

Answer (score 10):

I tried doing the below steps in an [official](https://hub.docker.com/r/kalilinux/kali-rolling) docker image of Kali Linux. It should work on the desktop as well.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y build-essential openssl openssl-dev* wget curl
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.8/Python-3.7.8.tgz
tar -xvf Python-3.7.8.tgz
cd Python-3.7.8
./configure --enable-shared
make 
make test
make install

# Steps from here are to enable other libraries in linux to 
# access the shared python libraries.

cd /usr/local/lib/
cp libpython3.so /usr/lib64/
cp libpython3.so /usr/lib
cp libpython3.7m.so.1.0 /usr/lib64/
cp libpython3.7m.so.1.0 /usr/lib/
cd /usr/lib64
ln -s libpython3.7m.so.1.0 libpython3.7m.so
cd /usr/lib
ln -s libpython3.7m.so.1.0 libpython3.7m.so
```

Done, python3.7 is installed.

```
root@fe794c7ff15e:~# python3
Python 3.7.8 (default, Aug 15 2020, 16:26:34)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I tried creating a python virtual environment with this install. It worked properly. I was able to install pip packages as well.

```
(testvirtual) root@fe794c7ff15e:~# pip install flask
Collecting flask
  Downloading Flask-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 94 kB 404 kB/s 
Collecting Jinja2>=2.10.1
  Downloading Jinja2-2.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 125 kB 10.4 MB/s 
Collecting click>=5.1
  Downloading click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 82 kB 165 kB/s 
Collecting Werkzeug>=0.15
  Downloading Werkzeug-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 298 kB 11.9 MB/s 
Collecting itsdangerous>=0.24
  Downloading itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23
  Downloading MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (27 kB)
Installing collected packages: MarkupSafe, Jinja2, click, Werkzeug, itsdangerous, flask
Successfully installed Jinja2-2.11.2 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 Werkzeug-1.0.1 click-7.1.2 flask-1.1.2 itsdangerous-1.1.0
```

Comment: Cp says there is no /use/lib64/

Comment: Does copying required files to /usr/lib only work ?

Comment: Try running these commands as root and then try again if it works. 
mkdir -p /usr/lib64   
cp libpython3.so /usr/lib64/  
cp libpython3.7m.so.1.0 /usr/lib64/
cd /usr/lib64 
ln -s libpython3.7m.so.1.0 libpython3.7m.so

Comment: replaced `/usr/lib64/` with `/usr/libx86_64-linux-gnu/`, and there is no python binary in `/usr/bin/`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Default Python version in Ubuntu nowadays is 3.8 which is per-installed.
While it looks like older version of spark like 2.x versions require Python version 3.7.
I ran into same issue and I did the below

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt install python3.7
```

Updated bashrc to point PYSPARK_PYTHON environment variable to python3.7 installed above like below

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.7
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 2):

The following commands seem to work, but bear in mind the disclaimer about [the deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa):

> [T]here's no guarantee of timely updates in case of security problems or other issues. If you want to use them in a security-or-otherwise-critical environment (say, on a production server), you do so at your own risk.

But, if you really want to do this:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install python3 python3-pip software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
apt-get install python3.7
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry. I realized that too when trying it in a Kali Docker container. It does work in Ubuntu, however.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I follow when starting a new Python project:

First I decide on a Python release.  Let's say you want to work with Python 3.7.8.

To install a specific release, I use `pyenv`.  It's on [gitbug](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and use [this script](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer) to install it.

After installing pyenv you should `cd` to the place your code will be and enter `pyenv install 3.7.8` and `pyenv local 3.7.8` which will make sure that the Python 3.7.8 environment will be created at that location.

Then you install [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/): `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python`.

After poetry is installed (use `poetry -V` to see if it works), you can run `poetry init` to create a `pyproject.toml` file.

You can add new dependencies like this: `poetry add requests`.

And you can enter that environment via `poetry shell`.

Now your using your new project in your specific 3.7.8 python version using your dependencies in a separate shell.