# no module named distutils....but distutils installed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, distutils

I was wanting to upgrade my python version (to 3.10 in this case) so after installing python3.10 I proceeded to try adding some modules I use e.g. opencv , which ran into:

```
jeremy@jeremy-Blade:~$ python3.10 -m pip install opencv-python 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 19, in <module>
    from distutils.util import strtobool
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'

jeremy@jeremy-Blade:~$ sudo apt-get install python3-distutils
[sudo] password for jeremy: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-distutils is already the newest version (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04).
...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

Since distutils already seems to be installed , I can't grok how to proceed.

Comment: For me, `pip install disutils` fixed the problem. I had python 3.7

Comment: it's related to your python version.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It looks like distutils has versioning , so after

```
jeremy@jeremy-Blade:~$ sudo apt-get install python3.10-distutils 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
...
Setting up python3.10-lib2to3 (3.10.0-1+focal1) ...
Setting up python3.10-distutils (3.10.0-1+focal1) ...

jeremy@jeremy-Blade:~$ python3.10 -m pip install opencv-python
```

seems to be able to proceed.

Comment: Didnt work for me I still get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'"

Comment: sorry I'm not sure what would cause that , can you post the whole errmsg or maybe start a new question?

Answer (score 86):

Install **setuptools** in your machine

```
pip install setuptools
```

This solved my problem

Comment: For people who has python latest(3.12) this worked. Can someone explain me why ? Thanks

Comment: You can check the PR gh-95299 which states: Do not pre-install setuptools in virtual environments created with venv. This means that distutils, setuptools, pkg_resources, and easy_install will no longer available by default; to access these run pip install setuptools in the activated virtual environment.

Comment: worked on fedora39 linux. the package is needed to work with gradio package

Comment: @AravindReddy check the answer above https://stackoverflow.com/a/76691103/4245534

Comment: pip3 install setuptools

Answer (score 74):

`distutils` package is removed in `python version 3.12`

> It was deprecated in Python 3.10 by PEP 632 “Deprecate distutils module”. For projects still using distutils and cannot be updated to something else, the setuptools project can be installed: it still provides distutils.

Edit: **Explanation and workaround**:

Python 3.12 Release document mentions :

> [gh-95299](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/95299https://): Do not pre-install setuptools in virtual environments created with venv. This means that distutils, setuptools, pkg_resources, and easy_install will no longer available by default; to access these run pip install setuptools in the activated virtual environment.

**https://docs.python.org/3.12/whatsnew/3.12.html**

---

so as @MahmudAlam answered:

use below command in your **virtual environment**

```
pip install setuptools
```

or

```
pip3 install setuptools
```

---

Full migration advice : **https://peps.python.org/pep-0632/#migration-advice**

Comment: what is the replacement for distutils in py3.12+?

Comment: Not a replacement as such but, you can install setuptools in your virtual environment for your needs.

Answer (score 12):

This solved it for me

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3.7-distutils
```

You can also replace 3.7 with your version of python

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo apt-get install python3.9-distutils
```

This solved my problem i am using Python3.9

Answer (score 4):

If it is possible, you can try to downgrade your python version below 3.12 i.e. 3.11 or lower

Comment: Yes! If you install python3.12-dev on Ubuntu 22.04, it may break packages that rely on distutils such as ament-cmake-python.

Comment: Yep, experiencing this on a CircleCI Electron app build pipeline right now. Ugh.

Answer (score 3):

Install `distutils` for your-python-version

```
!sudo apt-get install python<your-python-version>-distutils
```

For example, to install in 3.8 version

```
sudo apt-get install python3.8-distutils
```

> Specification: In Python 3.10 and 3.11, distutils will be formally marked as deprecated. All known issues will be closed at this time.

***Note***: You could still use `distutisl` with warning in `3.10` and `3.11` and any issues that arises will not be fixed. But, Code that imports distutils will no longer work from Python 3.12.

For more info: [Migragtion Advice](https://peps.python.org/pep-0632/#migration-advice)

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem

```
sudo apt-get install python3.10-distutils
```

I am using python 3.10

Answer (score 0):

I faced with that problem on Windows and other answers didn't help. That's because I have two versions of Python3 (3.8 and 3.12) on my machine. In this case call:

```
pip3 install setuptools
```

just installs `setuptools` for Python 3.8:

```
$ pip3 install setuptools
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in  
  c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (69.2.0)
```

Meanwhile `python3` refers to another version:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.12.2
```

To correctly install `setuptools` I have to run `pip` in a different way:

```
python3 -m pip install setuptools
```

Answer (score -2):

```
py -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

my problem was i couldn't use pip or sudo to install anything so the above command reinstalled pip and fixed the issue. hope that helps anyone else looking for a solution.