# No module named 'distutils.util'

Tags: python-3.x, distutils

I'm working on ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS and While creating a virtual environment in python 3.8 I'm getting No module named 'distutils.util'

I'm using the repository: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`
I have tried the following but didn't work

```
sudo apt install python3-distutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-distutils
```

[I have tried the solution from this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239202/unable-to-locate-package-python3-distutils-in-ubuntu-16-04)

```
sudo apt install python3.8-distutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.8-distutils
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.8-distutils'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.8-distutils'
```

Comment: afaik it's a built-in module. that is, you shouldn't need to install separately. was your Python 3.8 installation done correctly?

Comment: The linked solution is outdated. [deadsnakes](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+index) now supports Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic) and Ubuntu 20.04 (focal). Not Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @ mechanical_meat sure the python 3.8 was installed correctly

Comment: @ Phd is there another package that supports both python 3.6 and ubuntu 16

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76691103/13086128

Answer (score 15):

Make sure to replace `3.10` which is version of `python` with appropriate version.

## Installing Python3.10

```
Update system
    $ sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get full-upgrade -y

Helps to add ppa repositories
    $ sudo apt install software-properties-common -y

Adding deadsnake repository
    $ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa

Installing python
    $ sudo apt-get install python3.10
    $ sudo apt-get install python3.10-dev
    $ sudo apt-get install python3.10-tk

Add Python 3.8 & Python 3.10 to update-alternatives
    $ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 1
    $ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.10 2

Update Python 3 for point to Python 3.10
    $ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

## Installing `distutils.util`

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3.10-distutils
```

Still using `python3.10 -m pip some_command` might result in **error** to fix it use

```
$ curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.10
```

Comment: this should be an accepted response /