# Why did I got an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, skfuzzy, python-3.12

I've installed `scikit-fuzzy` but when I `import skfuzzy as fuzz` I get an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'"
```

I already tried to `pip uninstall distutils` and got this output

```
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
WARNING: Skipping distutils as it is not installed.
```

Then I tried to install it again `pip install distutils`

```
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement distutils (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for distutils
```

Since I use **Python 3.12** I also tried to use `pip3` to install but it say invalid syntax.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76691103/13086128

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Python 3.12 does not come with a stdlib distutils module ([changelog](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html)), because `distutils` was deprecated in 3.10 and removed in 3.12. See [*PEP 632 – Deprecate distutils module*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0632/).

You can still use `distutils` on Python 3.12+ by installing `setuptools`.

When that doesn't work, you may need stay on Python < 3.12 until the 3rd-party package (`skfuzzy` in this case) publishes an updated release for Python 3.12 support.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked! But now I have another problem, it said [ ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp' ]. Is there any module that I have to install?

Comment: Yes [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#imp) was also removed, and there is no backport that I'm aware of. You may have to downgrade Python version, it sounds like `skfuzzy` is not ready to run on Python 3.12 yet.

Comment: It looks like scikit-fuzzy has already fixed the distutils issue in [#296](https://github.com/scikit-fuzzy/scikit-fuzzy/pull/296) (Dec 2022) _and_ the imp issue in [#265](https://github.com/scikit-fuzzy/scikit-fuzzy/pull/265) (Sep 2020), however the package hasn't had a release since [0.4.2 in Nov 2019](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-fuzzy/0.4.2/). Perhaps you could install directly from [this branch](https://github.com/scikit-fuzzy/scikit-fuzzy/pull/310) in the meantime.

Comment: I'm getting this error too. Deprecate it but don't remove it. It breaks projects. IIUC The benefit of npm is preventing everything from breaking as libraries are updated.

Comment: Python downloads page https://www.python.org/downloads/

Answer (score 10):

`distutils` module is used to install python packages. This module usually installed as part of python installation.

In python v3.12, `distutils` module removed. This means your local doesn't have any tool in place to support python package installation.

To resolve this issue, install `setuptools` for same purpose.

Run the command `python3 -m pip install setuptools`

Comment: In 3.12 you cannot install setuptools as it still uses distutils

Answer (score 3):

```
brew install python-setuptools
```

if you are using mac and use homebrew then use above command to install missing module

Comment: Great this works for me. I used homebrew installed python (Python 3.12.2)

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same issue while importing tensorflow.

My solution was to follow below steps,

1. install setuptools
2. import setuptools.dist

Then tensorflow was imported without any "**ModuleNotFoundError**" error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ***Void Linux*** you can solve this by runnig the following command:

```
xi python3-setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

## For Poetry users:

I had the same problem while using poetry.

I had python 3.12 installed on a new machine and my pyproject.toml said:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
```

However, it was not "smart" enough to detect that python 3.12 is installed which has no setuptools.

So changing poetry to

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.12"
```

and running

```
poetry lock
poetry install
```

made everything work again.

Answer (score -5):

if you found this error the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'` that mean some library missing in your python. firstly you open your terminal and write.

`pip install setuptools`
`pip install poetry` 
`pip install pipenv`
`pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: ...why would installing Poetry and Pipenv be part of the solution?

Comment: please make sure to provide more clear and thorough answers in the future and properly consider other users comments and answers.