# Cannot Instal mamba on Python 3.12

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, mamba

I'm trying to get mamba to run on Spyder 5.5.3 with Python 3.8.10 64-bit | Qt 5.15.2 | PyQt5 5.15.10 | Windows 10 (AMD64)

when I run !mamba install bs4==4.10.0 -y

[image]

Note !pip install yfinance==0.1.67 installs successfully.

I've previously followed:

[Why did I got an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77233855/why-did-i-got-an-error-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-distutils)

which may have changed the error code, but I still gent no good results

I've additionally reset my python interpreter to

C:/Users/#####/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe

And yes I have closed and reopened, spyder, reset my kernal, and turned my box on and off again.

How do i get mamba to install?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are trying to install mamba by executing a command named "mamba"?

Comment: All I know i know i that when I invoke !mamba is that I get an error.  I would assume that !mamba install means that I'm installing it.  The code comes from a common learning project.

Comment: You get an error which tells you that there is no command named mamba. You first need to install it by some other means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you don't have mamba installed.
In the screenshot you posted, you are attempting to use (uninstalled) mamba to install a package called bs4

Here is mamba's own documentation on how to [install mamba](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/mamba-installation.html)