ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils' in python 3.12.2
When I try to run
with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:

in Python 3.12.2, I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):     with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\nguye\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 80, in __init__     self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\nguye\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 111, in get_pyaudio     from distutils.version import LooseVersion ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'


https://stackoverflow.com/a/77233866/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-3.12%5D+%22No+module+named+distutils%22

Does this answer your question? Why did I got an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'?
