Anaconda Navigator Fails to Start with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
The anaconda navigator suddenly stoped working from today(17-10-2024).
C:\ProgramData\anaconda3>anaconda-navigator Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in <module> from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 19, in <module> from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 32, in <module> from anaconda_navigator.widgets.main_window import MainWindow File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window\__init__.py", line 28, in <module> from anaconda_navigator.api.anaconda_api import AnacondaAPI File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 29, in <module> from anaconda_navigator.api.client_api import ClientAPI File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\client_api.py", line 21, in <module> import binstar_client File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\binstar_client\__init__.py", line 15, in <module> from pkg_resources import parse_version as pv File "C:\Users\Chaithanya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 90, in <module> import packaging.markers File "C:\Users\Chaithanya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\packaging\markers.py", line 25, in <module> from .specifiers import InvalidSpecifier, Specifier File "C:\Users\Chaithanya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\packaging\specifiers.py", line 14, in <module> from .utils import canonicalize_version File "C:\Users\Chaithanya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\packaging\utils.py", line 9, in <module> from .tags import Tag, parse_tag File "C:\Users\Chaithanya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\packaging\tags.py", line 7, in <module> import distutils.util ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
when i try laucning it using ui it doesnot even show in the task manager
I tried to install distutils but it cannot be installed because of discontinuation.
Even tried to uninstall and install but still same.
It is not working in my friends laptop from today.

You can install distutils: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77233866/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ModuleNotFoundError%3A+%22No+module+named+distutils%22

And if you cannot install distutils downgrade Python to a version that has distutils. Try Python 3.11.
