# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils' in Python 3.12

Tags: python, pip, modulenotfounderror, customtkinter, python-3.12

When I try to import `customtkinter` in Python 3.12, I get the following error:

```
  File "c:\Users\judel\OneDrive\Documents\Python\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import customtkinter as ttk
  File "C:\Users\judel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .windows.widgets.appearance_mode import AppearanceModeTracker
  File "C:\Users\judel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .ctk_tk import CTk
  File "C:\Users\judel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\ctk_tk.py", line 2, in <module>
    from distutils.version import StrictVersion as Version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
```

Why is this happening? Why can't a module from the standard library be found?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 38):

It appears that [`customtkinter`](https://pypi.org/project/customtkinter/0.3/) uses [`distutils`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/distutils.html) from the standard library.

Unfortunately, you're using the [newly released Python 3.12, which removed `distutils`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html) after it being deprecated  since Python 3.10. See [PEP 632 Deprecate distutils module](https://peps.python.org/pep-0632/) and [gh-92584](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/92584) for more details about its removal.

If you want to use that distribution, you'll need to either

1. install [`setuptools`](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/), which now also provides `distutils`, or
2. sideload `distutils` from a third party source (e.g. a system package, like `apt install python3-distutils`), or
3. downgrade to an older version of Python (3.11 or older), or
4. wait for its maintainer to update it to support Python 3.12.

Comment: In my case `setuptools-65.7.0` has been installed but it still raises the exception. It gets fixed after updating it to `68.2.2` by `python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools`.

Comment: worked to fix gradio package problems: `pip install setuptools`

Comment: "pip install setuptools" still raises the exception

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76691103/13086128