# No module named 'distutils' despite setuptools installed

Tags: python, conda, setuptools, distutils, python-3.12

I get

```shell
$ pip install -e .
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
```

with Python 3.12 despite

```shell
$ conda install setuptools
...
All requested packages already installed.
$ pip install setuptools
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\...\appdata\local\miniconda3\envs\c312\
lib\site-packages (69.0.3)
```

My `pyproject.toml` is

```toml
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "zzz"
authors = [
    ...
]
description = "zzz"
readme = "README.md"
version = "36"
dependencies = [
    "numpy",
    "pandas",
]

[project.optional-dependencies]
test = [
    "coverage",
]
speed = [
    "python-rapidjson",
]

[project.urls]
Homepage = "..."

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
exclude = ["tests"]

[tool.pylint.'MESSAGES CONTROL']
max-bool-expr = 10
```

My setup with `miniconda3`:

```shell
$ conda create --name c312 python=3.12 pandas matplotlib scipy scikit-learn ...
...
$ conda activate c312
$ which pip
/c/Users/.../AppData/Local/miniconda3/envs/c312/Scripts/pip
$ pip --version
pip 23.3.2 from C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\c312\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.12)
$ conda --version
conda 23.11.0
$ which python
/c/Users/.../AppData/Local/miniconda3/envs/c312/python
$ python
Python 3.12.1 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Dec 23 2023, 07:53:56) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)]
on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import setuptools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ssteingold\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\c312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__
.py", line 8, in <module>
    import distutils.core
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
>>> import distutils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
>>>
$ conda list '^(python|setuptools)$'
# packages in environment at C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\c312:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
python                    3.12.1          h2628c8c_1_cpython    conda-forge
setuptools                69.0.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
```

**what am I doing wrong?**

**PS**. The following questions

- [Why did I got an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77233855/850781)
- [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils' in Python 3.12](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77247893/850781)

basically say "install `setuptools`" - but I already have it (and shouldn't it be auto-installed because I require it in `pyproject`?)

The question [Unable to import a module that is definitely installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14295680/850781) has nothing to do with mine.

## ANSWER

Unset `SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS` (it was set to `stdlib` for the sake of broken `msys/python`).

Comment: Could you confirm that conda uses the same python version as pip in the first command?

Comment: @DanielPerezEfremova - yes, it does

Comment: Can you import `setuptools`? Could you show where it is loaded from? Also what does importing `distutils` show in an interactive session - is it different? Please share the package info on the `python` and `setuptools` packages, so others can minimally recreate. I.e., add `conda list '^(python|setuptools)$'` output to question body.

Comment: See https://peps.python.org/pep-0632/#migration-advice (PEP-632 proposed removal of distutils).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: you can see that the I get `setuptools ` from `...miniconda3\envs\c312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__
.py`  so it _should_ be the correct version.

Comment: Here's a question: Do you have a package named `_distutils_hack` installed? (That package is provided by setuptools and creates a `sys.modules` entry for distutils, preventing any later `import distutils` from _actually_ looking for a distutils file on-disk).

Comment: Alternately... any chance you might have an environment variable `SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS` defined? If so, what's its value?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: yes, `import _distutils_hack ` succeeds. It's in `\miniconda3\envs\c312\Lib\site-packages\_distutils_hack`. I did not install it manually

Comment: _After_ you run `import _distutils_hack`, can you then `import distutils`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: indeed I set `SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS=stdlib` (required by msys - when I still hoped to get msys/python working).

Comment: Ahh! `SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS` needs to be set to the string `local`, or be unset, for the setuptools magic that replaces distutils to work.

Comment: You can't use `stdlib` in Python 2.13 because there **is** no standard-library distutils on Python 2.13; it was removed per PEP-632.

Comment: 2.13 never existed and will never exist ;-)

Comment: Er, right. I've been guilty of that typo over and over in recent weeks (which have involved rather a lot of patching dependencies to build on 3.12).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is taking place because you have `SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS=stdlib` set in your environment, while Python 3.12 no longer provides any standard-library distutils version at all. There *is* no longer any "stdlib" distutils, so it cannot be selected.

---

To go into the mechanism a bit:

`setuptools` provides a module `_distutils_hack`, which when loaded replaces `sys.modules['distutils']` to point to `setuptools._distutils`; however, it *only* does this when `SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS` is either unset or has the value `'local'`.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

Seems a version problem. pip and conda are using different binaries.

Run

```
pip --version
```

to confirm that it points to the virtual env you expected to. You should see something like

```
pip 23.3.1 from <your path>\envs\<env name>\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.12)
```

## Solution

Create a Python 3.12 env, activate it and run the installation. I tested it and it does not have any dependencies problem.

```
conda create env -n py312 python=3.12
conda activate py312 
python -m pip install -e .
```

Comment: yep, that's what I already did!

Comment: worked as expected?

Comment: I did your "solution" before I asked this question.

Comment: IOW, your "solution" is exactly how I got the problem.