# distutils not found when running npm install

Tags: npm, node-gyp

I'm a NODE novice and trying to install and run https://github.com/DylanAkp/AirtagsAnywhere

I'm on a brand new M2 Mac with Python 3.12

Node 18.18 and NPM 9.8.1

And get a long stream. I understand the warnings but can't follow the errors.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path /Users/airtag/Desktop/AirtagsAnywhere/front_airtags/node_modules/node-sass
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
    npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/airtag/Desktop/AirtagsAnywhere/front_airtags/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
    npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/airtag/Desktop/AirtagsAnywhere/front_airtags/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
    npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
    npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.18.0 | darwin | arm64
    npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
    npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
    npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
    npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
    npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
    npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
    npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if "python3" can be used
    npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "python3" to get executable path
    npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executable path is "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3"
    npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3" to get version
    npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - version is "3.12.0"
    npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.0 found at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3"
    npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 18.18.0
    npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '18.18.0' ]
    npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "18.18.0"
    npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 18.18.0
    npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
    npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
    npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
    npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
    npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
    npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 18.18.0
    npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /Users/airtag/Desktop/AirtagsAnywhere/front_airtags/node_modules/node-sass/build
    npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? Yes
    npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
    npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: /Users/airtag/Desktop/AirtagsAnywhere/front_airtags/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
    npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/airtag/Desktop/AirtagsAnywhere/front_airtags/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
    npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/airtag/Desktop/AirtagsAnywhere/front_airtags/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
    npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/airtag/Desktop/AirtagsAnywhere/front_airtags/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/airtag/Desktop/AirtagsAnywhere/front_airtags/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/airtag/Desktop/AirtagsAnywhere/front_airtags/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/airtag/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.18.0/include/node/common.gypi',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/airtag/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.18.0',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/airtag/Desktop/AirtagsAnywhere/front_airtags/node_modules/node-gyp',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/airtag/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.18.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/airtag/Desktop/AirtagsAnywhere/front_airtags/node_modules/node-sass',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
    npm ERR! Traceback (most recent call last):
    npm ERR!   File "/Users/airtag/Desktop/AirtagsAnywhere/front_airtags/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 42, in <module>
    npm ERR!     import gyp  # noqa: E402
    npm ERR!     ^^^^^^^^^^
    npm ERR!   File "/Users/airtag/Desktop/AirtagsAnywhere/front_airtags/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    npm ERR!     import gyp.input
    npm ERR!   File "/Users/airtag/Desktop/AirtagsAnywhere/front_airtags/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 19, in <module>
    npm ERR!     from distutils.version import StrictVersion
    npm ERR! ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/airtag/Desktop/AirtagsAnywhere/front_airtags/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:259:16)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:292:12)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 23.0.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/airtag/Desktop/AirtagsAnywhere/front_airtags/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/airtag/Desktop/AirtagsAnywhere/front_airtags/node_modules/node-sass
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.18.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
    npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/airtag/.npm/_logs/2023-10-07T19_25_34_725Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no module named distutils....but distutils installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69919970/no-module-named-distutils-but-distutils-installed)

Answer (score 13):

`distutils` module is used to install python packages for node gyp. This module usually installed as part of python installation.

In python v3.12, `distutils` module removed. This means your local doesn't have any tool in place to support python package installation for node gyp.

So when node gyp try to install python package using distutils that is not installed as part of python, the above issue happen.

To resolve this issue, I would suggest you to install recommended tool called `setuptools` for same purpose.

Run the command `python3 -m pip install setuptools`

Comment: This worked for me. But what's the difference between `python3 -m pip install setuptools` and just `pip install setuptools` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69919970#answer-76691103)?

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. You've saved me a lot of time.

Comment: this never worked for me, First off, I had to use a flag to override behavior since I didn't want to setup a virtual env. ``python3 -m pip install distutils --break-system-packages`

But then it just kept saying 
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement distutils (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for distutils`

had to go to use @Alexander Kondaurov's answer

Answer (score 6):

I solved it, I'm a mac user:

`disutils` is not supported anymore starting from python3.12

install python 3.11

`brew install python@3.11`

setup environment variable in .zshrc

`export PYTHON=3.11`

now you use python@3.11 by default

Comment: a savior. although `export PYTHON=3.11` didn't set python version for me, I used `export npm_config_python=/opt/homebrew/bin/python3.11`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the relevant part of the message:

"from distutils.version import StrictVersion npm ERR! ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils' npm"

distutils has been removed from Python 3.12. either roll back to Python 3.11.x or open a ticket against the package and have the build process fixed.