# I can't run pip install, it's giving this error in djnago's python, I want to run "pip install -r requirements.txt "

Tags: django

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main> pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting absl-py==2.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached absl_py-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.3 kB)
Collecting astunparse==1.6.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached astunparse-1.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting cachetools==5.3.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached cachetools-5.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.2 kB)
Collecting certifi==2023.7.22 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached certifi-2023.7.22-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer==3.3.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Using cached charset_normalizer-3.3.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (33 kB)
Collecting flatbuffers==23.5.26 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Using cached flatbuffers-23.5.26-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (850 bytes)
Collecting gast==0.5.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Using cached gast-0.5.4-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting google-auth==2.23.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Using cached google_auth-2.23.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.2 kB)
Collecting google-auth-oauthlib==1.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
  Using cached google_auth_oauthlib-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting google-pasta==0.2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
  Using cached google_pasta-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
Collecting grpcio==1.59.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
  Using cached grpcio-1.59.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (4.2 kB)
Collecting h5py==3.10.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
  Using cached h5py-3.10.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.5 kB)
Collecting idna==3.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
  Using cached idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting keras==2.14.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
  Using cached keras-2.14.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.4 kB)
Collecting libclang==16.0.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
  Using cached libclang-16.0.6-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (5.3 kB)
Collecting Markdown==3.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
  Using cached Markdown-3.5-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.1 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe==2.1.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
  Using cached MarkupSafe-2.1.3-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting ml-dtypes==0.2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 18))
  Using cached ml_dtypes-0.2.0.tar.gz (698 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 2
  ╰─> [100 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version < "3.11"' don't match your environment
      Collecting numpy~=1.23.3
        Using cached numpy-1.23.5.tar.gz (10.7 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
      ERROR: Exception:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 180, in exc_logging_wrapper
          status = run_func(*args)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 245, in wrapper
          return func(self, options, args)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 377, in run
          requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 95, in resolve
          result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 546, in resolve
          state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 397, in resolve
          self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 173, in _add_to_criteria
          if not criterion.candidates:
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 156, in __bool__
          return bool(self._sequence)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
          return any(self)
                 ^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
          return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
          candidate = func()
                      ^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 211, in _make_candidate_from_link
          self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 293, in __init__
          super().__init__(
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 156, in __init__
          self.dist = self._prepare()
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 225, in _prepare
          dist = self._prepare_distribution()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 304, in _prepare_distribution
          return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 525, in prepare_linked_requirement
          return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 640, in _prepare_linked_requirement
          dist = _get_prepared_distribution(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 71, in _get_prepared_distribution
          abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\sdist.py", line 54, in prepare_distribution_metadata
          self._install_build_reqs(finder)
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\sdist.py", line 124, in _install_build_reqs
          build_reqs = self._get_build_requires_wheel()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\sdist.py", line 101, in _get_build_requires_wheel
          return backend.get_requires_for_build_wheel()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 751, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return super().get_requires_for_build_wheel(config_settings=cs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_impl.py", line 166, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._call_hook('get_requires_for_build_wheel', {
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_impl.py", line 321, in _call_hook
          raise BackendUnavailable(data.get('traceback', ''))
      pip._vendor.pyproject_hooks._impl.BackendUnavailable: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\template-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
          obj = import_module(mod_path)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1304, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1325, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 929, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:\Users\windows-10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-l6rs3m53\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
          import distutils.core
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
```

**  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 2
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.**

I already updated my python to 11.5, 12.5, 13.0 but nothing, it ran on my friends' computer and we were on the same version, someone help me!! I already put it on chatGPT but it didn't help at all.

Comment: Does this answer help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69919970/no-module-named-distutils-but-distutils-installed

Comment: It appears a package you are trying to install needs Python less than 3.11; try it on 3.10?

Comment: Add your requirements.txt to question. But you can see some error in final of output `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'`