# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils' how to solve this in MacOS

Tags: python, module, speech-recognition, pyaudio, microphone

Was trying to make python use speech recognition

```
File "/Users/hridayjain/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    text=takeCommand()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/hridayjain/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/main.py", line 8, in takeCommand
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/hridayjain/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/hridayjain/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 111, in get_pyaudio
    from distutils.version import LooseVersion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
```

got this error though.

i was seeing a video from Code With Harry and tried making Jarvis with it but got stuck in this part where its not able to recognize my speech

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no module named distutils....but distutils installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69919970/no-module-named-distutils-but-distutils-installed)

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following code:

pip install setuptools