cannot run the server with python manage.py runserver
(env) C:\Users\aurel\project\Lushlyrics-insecure>python manage.py runserver
C:\Users\aurel\project\Lushlyrics-insecure\distutils.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aurel\project\Lushlyrics-insecure\manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "C:\Users\aurel\project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
  File "C:\Users\aurel\project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\version.py", line 6, in <module>
    from distutils.version import LooseVersion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.version'; 'distutils' is not a package

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aurel\project\Lushlyrics-insecure\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\aurel\project\Lushlyrics-insecure\manage.py", line 12, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

Not able to run Python manage.py runserver. Got the error above.
I am trying to work on a project,
using git clone, but it is not working. When trying to runserver using Python manage.py runserver is not working.

Your/the project’s distutils.py is conflicting with the distutils that Django wants. Is python manage.py runserver the project’s documented way of starting the server? Probably a good idea to rename it and not add the project directory to Python’s sys.path anyway.

Maybe this will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69919970/no-module-named-distutils-but-distutils-installed
pip install setuptools
