Python module "distutils.util" in environment
I'm trying to install LST-AI (https://github.com/CompImg/LST-AI) on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS following the instruction listed in GitHub, but after setting up and activating the environment I try run the n°4 instruction:
git clone https://github.com/CompImg/LST-AI/
cd LST-AI
pip install -e .
cd ..

and getting a long list of errors with at the end ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
I've already tried to do sudo pip3 install setuptools in the virtual env or in my system without benefice.
(environment) giorgio@giorgio-XPS-15-9530:~/lst_directory$ sudo pip3 install setuptools
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

Is it necessary to downgrade phyton from 3.12 to 3.10 or there is another way to fix the problem?
I also try to do as in How do I solve "error: externally-managed-environment" every time I use pip 3? but it's not an application so pipx is not useful, and I've already set my virtual environment and running pip install -e . in it. Also tried pip install package_name --break-system-packages and I obtain the same error. Is there the possibility that somehow I've no permission to do this?

I'm almost convinced that happens because using sudo

I've alredy tried whitout , this is the error `  (environment) giorgio@giorgio-XPS-15-9530:~$ pip3 install setuptools
Collecting setuptools
Using cached setuptools-74.1.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.7 kB)
Using cached setuptools-74.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.3 MB)
Installing collected packages: setuptools
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/path/to/new/lst/virtual/environment/lib/python3.12/site-packages/distutils-precedence.pth'
Check the permissions.
`

This question is similar to: How do I solve "error: externally-managed-environment" every time I use pip 3?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69919970/no-module-named-distutils-util-but-distutils-installed, so yes, trying to install setuptools was correct.

"in the virtual env or in my system" - do it in the virtual environment, not in the system

"I've already tried to do sudo pip3 install setuptools in the virtual env or in my system without benefice." - in your own words, when you use sudo pip3 install setuptools, what do you believe is the purpose of sudo? When you use that command, do you expect it to try to install in the virtual env, or in the system? Why? If you wanted to do the other installation, what command would you use? Why? Did you try that command? What happens when you try it?

"I've alredy tried whitout ... Permission denied: '/path/to/new/lst/virtual/environment/lib/python3.12/site-packages/distutils-precedence.pth'- you cannot put a virtual environment into a path where you don't have write access, because the entire point of a virtual environment is to have a separate place to write the library files. The fundamental, underlying problem here is with the Unix security model and understanding whatsudo` actually is, what "system-wide" actually means, etc.
